# Collapse not working in ng-bootstrap and angular 4 app for navbar breadcrumb button

Tags: bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am using angular 4 and bootstrap 4 beta 2 and ng-bootstrap for my application and also using ng-bootstrap.

I have added the navbar from the bootstrap documentation example.

The code looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have also added bootstrap styles in angular-cli.json. That code looks like this:

```
 "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

The Breadcrumb button on the mobile view is not responding on its click. and when i tried to inspect the same: I got to know that "collapsed" class is not getting added to the button on click.
[image]

Comment: seems like you forgot to add JQuery/bootstrap.js

Comment: i am using ng-bootstrap where jquery is not required

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have a solution now. Just using ng-bootstrap solves your issue.

Html file:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"  aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Component ts file:

```
export class AppComponent {
  isCollapsed = false;
}
```

add bootstrap css file in angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

Add this in main module:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

imports: [
  NgbModule.forRoot()
]
```

This will work like a charm.

The main advantage of using ng-bootstrap is you can eliminate the dependencies of other js libraries like jquery and popper and you can also write your components for bootstrap.

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap' in '/home/www/angular/ngdemo/src/app'

Comment: @Jay Momaya did you install ng-bootstrap first? `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`  See here [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Why we need workaround for this? Why bootstrap default collapse functionality not working?

Comment: @HimalayaGarg maybe since jquery is not required in ng-bootstrap this functionality is not working properly

Comment: I tried this in Angular 11, but clicking the collapse menu still does not work.

Comment: Simple and veeeeery effective, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

Using ng-bootstrap (or in my case ngx-boostrap) definitely simplified things as I did not have to worry about jQuery and popper. As the currently accepted answer mentions.

However this did not solve my problem outright as I missed important details. After you have ngx-bootstrap up and running, you can start by binding the `collapse` property of the `navbar-collapse` div to a variable in your component file:

```
<div [collapse]="isCollapsed" class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
  ...
</div>
```

That alone isn't enough, and you actually need to modify this variable yourself (this is the part I missed) by binding to the click event of your toggler button:

```
<button (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main" aria-controls="navbar-main" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

`(click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"` being the fundamental missing piece for me. This binds the onClick event of the button to your isCollapsed variable, toggling it when clicked, and thus setting the `collapse` property of your navbar appropriately.

Here is the jsfiddle I found the ultimately helped me figure out my mistake:
[jsFiddle external link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-rc8ab4?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. However, i had to do [class.collapse]="isCollapsed" for Angular 9 not to throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Working Navbar

ng-bootstrap

Getting Started 
        
        
         Components 
        
        
         {{ component }}

```
 <span class="github-buttons d-none d-lg-inline"> 
   <a class="github-button" 
      href="https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" 
      target="_blank" 
      data-style="mega" 
      data-count-href="/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/stargazers" 
      data-count-api="/repos/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#stargazers_count" 
      data-count-aria-label="# stargazers on GitHub" 
      aria-label="Star ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap on GitHub">Star</a> 
   <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=ngbootstrap" 
      class="twitter-hashtag-button" 
      data-size="large" 
      data-text="I&#39;m checking out ng-bootstrap, THE Angular UI framework for Bootstrap CSS" 
      data-url="https://ng-bootstrap.github.io" 
      data-show-count="true">Tweet #ngbootstrap</a> 
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed using the below solution

component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow bg-body rounded">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{{ applicationName }}</a>
    <button #collapseButton class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation" (click)="togglePanel(collapseButton,collapsePanel)">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div #collapsePanel class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <div class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0"></div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-2">

            <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let navItem of navMenuList">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="navItem.path">
                    <mat-icon>{{navItem.icon}}</mat-icon> {{navItem.name}}
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
togglePanel(collapseButton: HTMLElement, collapsePanel: HTMLElement) {
if (this.isCollapsed) {
  collapseButton.classList.add('collapsed');
  collapsePanel.classList.remove('show');
} else {
  collapsePanel.classList.add('show');
  collapseButton.classList.remove('collapsed');
}
this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript files are not loaded. Add the following somewhere in your HTML code (preferably in the header):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/#js and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/javascript/ for more information.

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar plroblem. There is nothing complicated to do to make your angular project work. Just open index.html (main html file) and add js to it at the bottom of body:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).